# Problems with simulating my robot in a world with a heightmap

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

when I try to spawn my robot into my heightmap world, it can not drive at all. The height of my heightmap is 1m. But when I spawn my robot at 10m high it stands still at this position (floating in the air). Here is the SDF file of my heightmap model: [C:\fakepath\model_of_heightmap.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16334451311631152.png).

I also have a LIDAR sensor on my robot and the lasers should be visible in the gazebo world. For some reason these lasers are only visible when I spawn the robot at 10m high. So in short I have 2 problems: the robot can not drive in the heightmap world (which is possible in a world without a custom heightmap), and the second problem is that it wont show the LIDAR lasers.

I assume these 2 problems are related to each other. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27429/problems-with-simulating-my-robot-in-a-world-with-a-heightmap./) by [Hawkinator](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57116/hawkinator/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Apparently the performance will decrease massively when the size of the map is smaller than the number of pixels of the used grayscale image. So it worked for me loading in a 65x65 pixels grayscale image and making the size of the map 65x65 meters. This was the solution for me.

Kind regards!

---

Originally posted by [Hawkinator](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57116/hawkinator/) with karma: 1 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0